# Save List to IsolatedStorageSettings

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, serialization, windows-phone-8

I have this class :

```cs
class LyricsItem
{
    public LyricsItem()
    {

    }

    public LyricsItem(LyricsItem item)
    {
        this.searchUrl = item.searchUrl;
        this.croppingRegex = item.croppingRegex;
    }

    private string _searchUrl;
    private string _croppingRegex;

    public string searchUrl
    {
        get { return _searchUrl; }
        set { _searchUrl = value; }
    }

    public string croppingRegex
    {
        get { return _croppingRegex; }
        set { _croppingRegex = value; }
    }
}
```

And this is Array with items `LyricsItem` :

```
public List<LyricsItem> lyricsArray;
```

This is how i add items to the array :

```
    LyricsItem item = new LyricsItem();

    item.croppingRegex = croppingRegex;
    item.searchUrl = searchurl;

    lyricsArrayTmp.Add(item);
```

And i want to add it to `IsolatedStorageSettings`:

```
        IsolatedStorageSettings appSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
        if (appSettings.Contains("lyricsData"))
        {
            appSettings["lyricsData"] = lyricsArray;
        }
        else
        {
            appSettings.Add("lyricsData", lyricsArray);
        }

        appSettings.Save();
```

But When i get to save the IsolatedStorageSettings i get this exception:

```
The collection data contract type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[**********, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' cannot be deserialized because it does not have a public parameterless constructor. Adding a public parameterless constructor will fix this error. Alternatively, you can make it internal, and use the InternalsVisibleToAttribute attribute on your assembly in order to enable serialization of internal members - see documentation for more details
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't serialize a private class in the ApplicationSettings. Declare it as public instead:

```
public class LyricsItem
{
    public LyricsItem()
    {

    }

    public LyricsItem(LyricsItem item)
    {
        this.searchUrl = item.searchUrl;
        this.croppingRegex = item.croppingRegex;
    }

    private string _searchUrl;
    private string _croppingRegex;

    public string searchUrl
    {
        get { return _searchUrl; }
        set { _searchUrl = value; }
    }

    public string croppingRegex
    {
        get { return _croppingRegex; }
        set { _croppingRegex = value; }
    }
}
```